# Callback undefined in process.nextTick

Tags: javascript, node.js

Trying to recursively call a synchronous function to parse a element of the array; once the last element of the array is reached the callback is to be called. But the callback is said to be undefined when passed to  process.nextTick where as another variable declared in the same scope as the callback prints the proper value.

Can any one explain what am I doing wrong; how can the callback be undefined, where as another variable in the same scope is accessed properly.

```
someobject.prototype.launch = function (callback) {

    if (!this.config.children || this.config.children.length <= 0)
        throw new Error('No children found');
    var callCounter = 1;
    var _callback = function () {
        callback(true)
    };
    console.log(_callback); // prints [Function] as expected
    function create(i) {
        //some logic to process 
        //the 'i' element
        if (callCounter == stopAt) {
            var _callback = callback(true);
            //process.nextTick(_callback); //this too doesnt work as _callback is undefined
            process.nextTick(function () {
                console.log(callCounter + ' ' + _callback);
               // the callback is undefined where as callCounter holds the proper value. 
            });
        }else {
        //process.nextTick( (create.bind(this))(callCounter++));
        (create.bind(this))(callCounter++)
    }
     (create.bind(this))(0);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var _callback = callback(true);
```

this string can return undefined value. Are you shure that callback(true) return other function or value. Delete it or comment.

Example of undefined function result

```
var func_without_result = function(){};

console.log(func_without_result());
```

result

```
> undefined
```

Comment: console.log(_callback); // prints [Function] as expected; isnt this a proof that _callback is not undefined.. just checking.

Comment: console.log(_callback) - at the begining of your code. but into create function you reassign _callback with undefined value

Comment: If I directly invoke _callback(); it works. Where as from within the nextTick function its undefined.

Comment: can you comment this line? var _callback = callback(true);

Comment: in create function you use 'var _callback' and create new local variable _callback

Comment: Commenting the var _callback... and directly calling callback within the nextTick(function(){callback...}) helped. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54460/discussion-between-errol-dsilva-and-nikolay-lukyanchuk).